# Orion - pattern subscription to send multiple updates

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I use Orion to send updates to Proton-CEP when a change of an object occurs.

However, I have many such objects updates occurring every few seconds. So I send these updates to Orion in batches, like this:

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Queue",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Queue.routes_queue",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "volume",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "value": "3"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "type": "Queue",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Queue.optimizer_queue",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "volume",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "value": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

I have a subscription which is supposed to send these event (when the volume has changed) to CEP for processing.

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Queue",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": "Queue.*"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "volume"
    ],
    "reference": "http://<cep-host>:8080/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "volume"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
```

CEP is configured to listen to these events, and write them to a file. Unfortunately, only the first element is written.

I have confirmed that this is not a CEP problem by using the provided accumulator-server script. I can see only a single update being exposed:

```
POST http://localhost:1028/accumulate
Content-Length: 741
User-Agent: orion/0.24.0 libcurl/7.19.7
Host: localhost:1028
Accept: application/xml, application/json
Content-Type: application/xml

<notifyContextRequest>
  <subscriptionId>5645bb21abde60e23096acef</subscriptionId>
  <originator>localhost</originator>
  <contextResponseList>
    <contextElementResponse>
      <contextElement>
        <entityId type="Queue" isPattern="false">
          <id>Queue.routes_queue</id>
        </entityId>
        <contextAttributeList>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>volume</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <contextValue>4</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
        </contextAttributeList>
      </contextElement>
      <statusCode>
        <code>200</code>
        <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
      </statusCode>
    </contextElementResponse>
  </contextResponseList>
</notifyContextRequest>
=======================================

::1 - - [13/Nov/2015 10:29:05] "POST /accumulate HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Can Orion send updates for all elements that have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply to remove the throttling. Throttling applies to the entire subscription, not just to a single object in the matched pattern.